# IBM Mobilefirst WL.JSONStore fail to store large Json data in windows phone

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

I am using WL.JSONStore to store JSON data offline. But it gets failed in windows phone when my Json data is more than 2K.

It doesn't through any error and same code works fine in Android and iOS.

Here is my code.

```
WL.JSONStore
           .get(COLLECTION_NAME)
           .add(response.responseJSON.collection)
           .then(
            function (data) { <code> };
```

Comment: What is the Mobilefirst version you are using.And Are you using windows 10 UWP / windows 8.1 universal?

Comment: @ShubhaS I am using Mobilefirst 7.1 and windows phone 8.1

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying  the single JSON you are inserting is 2K ? Meaning 2 MB? or 2000 key value pairs? Just trying to see the size. Also, is this noted across your Windows devices? Or could this be only in devices with lower RAM ?

Comment: @VivinK Its around 5 MB of data and 2500 K key-value pairs.

Comment: And is the issue common to all WP8 devices or only few?

Comment: @VivinK I have two windows phone(8.1) and its common in both.

Comment: @Akhilesh We could not reproduce the issue.Can you please share the recreatable sample?Also please open a PMR for the same.